# Initializing field with null vs not initializing: what's the difference?

Tags: java, jvm, javac, bytecode

I wonder if there any difference between assigning the `null` value to the field versus not assigning it at all.

Let's compile simple class (either with javac or ecj):

```
public class Test {
    Object obj;
}
```

Now let's look to its bytecode:

```
$ javap -c Test.class
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  java.lang.Object obj;

  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #10                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

Now let's initialize the field:

```
public class Test {
    Object obj = null;
}
```

Now the constructor body looks different:

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  java.lang.Object obj;

  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: aconst_null
       6: putfield      #2                  // Field obj:Ljava/lang/Object;
       9: return
}
```

Both compilers don't simply ignore the initialization, they add an explicit `aconst_null/putfield` into constructor. So my question is: can this addition have any runtime consequences? Can I distinguish in runtime whether the object field was initialized to `null` or not initialized at all? If not, why compilers cannot just ignore this initialization?